# UIButton NSAttributedString won't update font color

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, nsmutablestring

I am trying to put a `string` on a button that has both a small image and text so I am using `NSMutableAttributedString` and `NSAttributedString`. From what I can tell the  `foregroundColor` key in the dictionary should update the color of text but it doesn't seem to be working. fgColor is `UIColor.white` and bgColor is `UIColor.black` but I have trouble printing that out to verify. Can anyone offer advice? Code is:

```
let myFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 8)
let dict1:[NSAttributedString.Key:Any] = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.font:myFont!,
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : fgColor,
        NSAttributedString.Key.strokeColor : fgColor,
        NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor : bgColor
]
let fullString = NSMutableAttributedString()
let imageAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
imageAttachment.image = UIImage(named:"ThumbsUpGreen")
let imageString = NSAttributedString(attachment: imageAttachment)
fullString.append(imageString)
fullString.append(NSAttributedString(string: " "+String(upCount), attributes: dict1))
thumbUpButton?.setAttributedTitle(fullString, for: .normal)
contentView.addSubview(thumbUpButton!)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you not planning having different colors in text, as alternative you can use UIButton's methods to color things out:
`thumbUpButton?.titleLabel?.textColor = fgColor
thumbUpButton?.backgroundColor = bgColor`

Comment: Thank you. That worked. The buttons are on a TableViewCell which is on a ViewController that is on one tab in a TabController. Now I have to figure out when a user switches to another tab and changes the background color, then switches back to this tab, how to update the button's title label inside the TableViewCell.

Comment: To answer my previous comment for anyone reading here: TableViewCells are reused when the view appears again. But, the tableview callbacks are executed so in the one that dequeues a cell and returns a "new" one, you can test for the button's existence, and update it's titleLabel if the button already exists (which it does in my case.)